# How to search recordsets with html entities

Tags: mysql, sql, html-entities

Most data in my database is stored with html entities, such as `&auml;` instead of `ä`. But some data is stored as plain text (`ä`).

Now I want to find all recordsets with `ä` OR ä. How can I optimally achieve this without using

SELECT id FROM table WHERE content LIKE '%`ä`%' OR content LIKE '%`&auml;`%'

Comment: The optimal way is probably to be consistent in your storage of such characters.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But that train has left the station ... i'll respect this in my future work, though.

Comment: you can't fix the code to insert new stuff in a consistent fashion and then update the data already in the tables?

Comment: It's too many tables with too many columns. I am afraid, I wouldn't find all occurencies.

Comment: You might think about triggers to normalize the data on insert/update until you've gone through the code... It shouldn't be too hard to write a script to generate the create trigger statements for each table

Answer (score 1):

You can search the table while replacing the values to be searched in the same query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REPLACE(content,'&auml;','ä') LIKE '%ä%'
```

You'll have to do the replace for all Umlaute of course.

Comment: You'll have to do it for upper case and lower case, too.

Answer (score 0):

Best answer is to go through your existing data and change all instances of the one to the other to be consistent.

Create a UDF

```
Create Function dbo.ReplaceHtmlEntities(@arg NVARCHAR(MAX) collate Latin1_General_Bin)
returns NVARCHAR(MAX) 
as
begin
   if @arg is null return @arg
   if not @arg like '%&%;%' return @arg
   -- Collation matters here obviously!!
   -- Auto generated lines
   -- These lines should be generated from a list of entities and Unicode values
   -- In practice you can limit this to the ones you actually have a problem with 
   set @arg = replace(@arg, '&Auml;' collate Latin1_General_BIN, char(0xUUUU))
   set @arg = replace(@arg, '&auml;' collate Latin1_General_BIN, char(0xUUUU))
   set @arg = replace(@arg, '&Ouml;' collate Latin1_General_BIN, char(0xUUUU))
   set @arg = replace(@arg, '&ouml;' collate Latin1_General_BIN, char(0xUUUU))
   -- For speed you can group them more common first, and short-circuit where possible
   if not @arg like '%&%;%' return @arg

   -- a lot more lines.... 
   return @arg
end
```

Then you just need to go through all your tables with that lot!!!!